# jekyll bootstrap toggle navigation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

I am making a personal blog using bootstrap and jekyll.
The problem is that when I reduce the screen size and click on the toggle menu in order to close it after it is expanded, it doesn't collapse.
I checked for every possible error but still toggle navigation isn't working once it is expanded.
The html page is correctly linking to all bootstrap css as well as js files. 
I just can't figure out what exactly is going wrong

Comment: It's difficult to help without seeing code. Did you have github repository ?

Comment: https://github.com/GetSetAbhi/test
Here's a link to my repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I get it.

You have two menus in your page.

The `index.html` does a `head.html` inclusion and the `default.html` template too.

index.html or any page or post is supposed to hold your content, not to take care of page decoration (eg: including head and footer).

To resolve your problem, in `index.html`, remove :

```
{% include head.html %}
{{ content }}
{% include footer.html %}
```

And add some html content like `<p>Hello world !</p>` and the magic will happen.

Happy Jekyll !

Comment: Thanks man..
It worked like magic ..
Now I guess i'm not much clear about the functionality of Jekyll.
So can you recommend some blog where jekyll is explained in a simple manner for beginners to understand ?

Comment: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/ and http://jekyllrb.com/docs/resources/ are good starting points.